# Getter on a object inheriting from multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python

As far is i know a object inheriting from multiprocessing.Process copies all it's variables into different memory to run as a separate Process. There are different ways of safely exchanging data between processes, however, it would still be possible to just call a getter in this object (like the example below). How unsafe is that?
And does this cause a major slowdown?

I just want to put some "metadata" into this object (name, priority, stuff like that), which is constant. If there is a better way to do that. I would be interested in that as well.

```py
class P(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, priority: int):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.priority = priority

    def getPriority(self):
        return self.priority
```

```py
p = P()
p.start()
p.getPriority()
```

Comment: You can experiment with the ideas you have presented - if you do please feel free to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Is the *meta-data* simple enough to construct as a string and  use it as the Processes `name` or part of its name?

Comment: @wwii It is simple enough to be put into a string. What would be the advantage of that?

Comment: You don't have to use a subclass - it is built in - and you don't have to worry about all those other things you asked about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it, it's pretty fast and it won't be trivial to implement something faster than build in solution. Internally the object sharing is done via object [pickling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#module-pickle). That will be used for exhanging objects between processes.